# Visual Studio Code Ctrl + comma does not work

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to search files by name in Visual Studio Code. All the answers said that the solution is to hit `ctrl` + `,`. But for me, the result is `Settings` window.

One solution that is closer to the answer is by hitting `ctrl` + `t`, but when the search bar appear, it has `#` symbol, which is not what i want. I want the search bar appear without any additional symbol so i can search file directly.

[image: This bar appear with # symbol when i press ctrl + t]

this is the information about my current visual studio code

```
Version: 1.70.1
Commit: 6d9b74a70ca9c7733b29f0456fd8195364076dda
Date: 2022-08-10T06:09:15.055Z
Electron: 18.3.5
Chromium: 100.0.4896.160
Node.js: 16.13.2
V8: 10.0.139.17-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.15.0-46-generic
```

Comment: Note **Visual Studio** and **Visual Studio Code** are different products. The solutions you found most likely talk about **Visual Studio**

Comment: in VSC use `Ctrl+P` and type part of the file name

Comment: yes, `ctrl + p`  does what i want @rioV8 @Alejandro 
ah i see.. i didnot realize that. thank you for pointing that out @Ivo